# Trying to use axios to query an API endpoint

Tags: javascript, vue.js, post, http-post

Hey I'm trying to get this mod.io example working. Here is an example curl they give

```
curl -X POST https://api.mod.io/v1/oauth/emailrequest \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'api_key=0d0ba6756d032246f1299f8c01abc424' \
  -d 'email=john.snow@westeros.com'
```

I am trying to add that to my Vue JS app but it returns a 401 error. Can anyone see anything wrong?

```
methods: {
loginUser() {
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  }
  console.log(this.email) //Works
  const data = {
    api_key: "0d0ba6756d032246f1299f8c01abc424",
    email: this.email
  }
  axios
  .post('https://api.mod.io/v1/oauth/emailrequest', data, {
    headers: headers
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

The API and email are from the docs so feel free to have a try with it.
[This](https://docs.mod.io/?shell#authenticate-via-email) is where i am struck

Is it possibly my localhost not being SSL?

Answer (score 1):

I knew I was close....

```
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
  const data = "api_key=0d0ba6756d032246f1299f8c01abc424&email="+this.email;
  
  axios
  .post('https://api.mod.io/v1/oauth/emailrequest', data, {
    headers: headers
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
```